# Each function for all the divs with contents

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs as follows;

```
<div class="error"></div>
<div class="error">foo</div>
<div class="error">bar</div>
<div class="error"></div>
<div class="error">ABC</div>
```

As you can see above, some of the div have contents and some of them do not. I need to select all the divs which have content for a jQuery each function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $('.error').each(function(index){
      var content = $(this).text();
      if(typeof content != 'undefined' && content!=''){
        //your code
      }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pnWc8/)

In the jsfiddle demo yiu can see into the your console the printed content inside div that aren't empty

Comment: there's no need to clutter jQuery answers with a `$(document).ready` handler unless you suspect the OP doesn't have one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.error').filter(function() {
    return $(this).html() != '';
});
```

`each` Example:

```
$('.error').filter(function() {
    return $(this).html() != '';
}).each(function(index, value) {
    console.log($(value).html());
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/aTTdC/)**

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use :not and :empty to filter out the blank divs as like below

```
$('.error:not(.error:empty)').each(function(){
  // Your code goes over here
});
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/tDwwg/

Answer (score 1):

`$('div.error:not(:empty)')`, will give you the elements

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, use `.not()` to exclude the `:empty` elements:

```
$('.error').not(':empty').each(...)
```